# Hide admin bar function

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to enable the admin bar on all pages but one titled "Registration" on my Wordpress site..The function below isnt working.. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
show_admin_bar( true );

if (is_page( 'registration' )) {

  show_admin_bar( false );
}
```

Comment: Where is this code? What theme file, and where in the file? As long as a page with title `registration` or slug `registration` exists, I see no reason this code shouldn't work.

Comment: @SetSailMedia its in my functions file

Comment: @SetSailMedia see edit.. does that first enable statement mess this up?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (is_page( 'registration' ) && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm still not working...does the true statement right above it cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since my previous suggestion did not suit your needs, have you tried this plugin?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-toolbar-removal/

Alternatively, you can check the functions.php file and search for the show_admin_bar function. Upon doing that, you can input the code shown above in either my post or Mooed's post.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this little piece of code in to the page:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Comment: its the default template so I cant do that.. i just need a the page titled "registration" to have no admin bar..

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```